# Accessing groovy getter instead of deferring to the @Delegate

Tags: groovy, delegates, annotations, javabeans, abstract-syntax-tree

Given the piece of code:

```
class Foo {
  @Delegate Map data

  Foo(data) { this.data = data }

  def getBar() { "Bar" }
}

new Foo([:]).bar // null
new Foo([:]).getBar() // "Bar"
```

It seems that the delegate is intercepting the call to `.bar` before it gets transformed into a call to the getter.  Is there anyway around this?  I would like to have a delegate to a map, but still be able to use the cleaner `.bar` at the call site to refer to the property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you get more than you actually want here (the property handling from the map -- at least this is my guess here).  Until someone finds a way to deal with this (`excludes` on the `@Delegate` did not work for me) you might be better off with just using the expando:

```
@groovy.transform.InheritConstructors
class Foo extends Expando {
    def getBar() { "Bar" }
}

def f = new Foo(baz:'baz')
assert f.foo==null
assert f.bar=="Bar"
assert f.getBar()=="Bar"
f.foo="F00"
assert f.foo=="F00"
assert f.baz=="baz"
```

Comment: Interesting solution, I think I like it better than my `withDefault` idea.  Since I'm wrapping an existing map, is there an easy way to populate an expando from a map instance?

Comment: ah, yup, just `new Foo(myMap)` seems to do it with the InheritConstructors transform.

Answer (score 0):

OK, cludgy solution, but changing the constructor to make a defaultMap from the given map to call the getter as a fallback seems to give me what I want

```
class Foo {
  @Delegate Map data

  Foo(data) { this.data = data.withDefault { "get${it.capitalize()}"() } }

  def getBar() { "got bar" }
}
```

This has the disadvantage of still preferring the map in the case where the map has an entry with key 'bar'.  Still hoping someone has a better solution.